# How to display only unique row and to remove from appear column

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible and how is possible to leave only unique values in column abc, and is it possible to not show column id1? 
My query is

```
SELECT
      br.id,LEFT( br.abc,3),
      d.id
FROM
     test br
LEFT  JOIN i_test2 d ON d.id LIKE concat(br.abc, '%')
WHERE
     d.id NOT LIKE '%0' AND d.id NOT LIKE '%9'
```

Result looks like:

```
id   abc   id1
1    C18   C181
2    C18   C182
3    D50   D504
4    D50   D506
5    D10   D106
6    D10   D107
```

I tried to solve also with adding

```
GROUP BY br.abc
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 (also i tried with HAVING COUNT(br.abc) but id didn't work)
```

At the end, result should looks like:

```
ID    abc
1     C18
3     D50
6     D10
```

Purpose of this is, i want to display values from table **test** that can't be reference on value in table test2 that ends with 0 or 9 because it not exist. And in result i want to see only unique value.

Comment: What is the logic behind your expectation?

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior! (When in WHERE, you'll get regular inner join result.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this;

```
SELECT
      MIN(br.id) id,
     LEFT(br.abc,3) abc
FROM
     test br
LEFT  JOIN i_test2 d ON d.id LIKE concat(br.abc, '%')
WHERE
     d.id NOT LIKE '%0' 
     AND d.id NOT LIKE '%9'
GROUP BY LEFT(br.abc,3)
```

It will give you the first appearance of your column 'abc' based upon the id of that row.

Comment: why i need to use twice LEFT ?

Comment: You need to group by that field for your aggregation (min) to work. Test it if you can use the alias of the field in the group by, I know in SQL Server that you can't use the alias of a calculated field in a group by.

Comment: i am using MySQL, and it works normal when i use ailas in select ,but in group i haven't used alias .. only problem is that time that is needed to get result is so long, reason i think is left join and like. Thank you

Comment: Now you've got a query that works, I'd open a new question about the performance as it's a different issue. Provide the query and the explain plan to give people as much information as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only unique `abc` values, then try using `DISTINCT`, and if you don't want the third column, then don't select it.  The answer below doesn't show any ID values, but then again your logic for choosing which one to display is not clear.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(br.abc,3) AS abc
FROM test br
LEFT JOIN i_test2 d
    ON d.id LIKE CONCAT(br.abc, '%')
WHERE d.id NOT LIKE '%0' AND
      d.id NOT LIKE '%9'
```

Comment: thank u, i think this works fine for my, but time to get result is so long, do u think there is possibility to get faster result?